# Push new changes to a branch whose master has moved forward

Tags: git, github, rebase, git-push, git-pull

Theres a master branch.
I have cloned master and created a new branch **devbranch** from the master branch and pushed changes to it.

The master has now moved forward.
I have cloned the new updated master again and made changes (almost repeated the changes in **devbranch**, but there are a some modifications).
I now want to push these changes made on the updated master to **devbranch**, basically as a fresh push, or as if I'm pushing it for the first time. (So that anyone who clones devbranch now, will get latest changes on the latest master).

What are my options ?

Comment: `I have cloned the new updated master again` ... did you really _clone_ again, or did you do something else?

Comment: I cloned it. 
I know it could have been done in a effiicient way but thats not the case

Comment: "clone" generally references the specific `git clone` command. From what you describe, it looks more like you did one of : `git checkout`, `git pull` or `git merge`. Can you please describe what action you ran when you say "cloned the new updated master" ? for example : which command did you type on the command line ? or which action did you run, using which tool ?

Comment: I ran `git clone --branch <branchname> <remote-repo>` 
both the times

Comment: Hi is there a specific reason you are using this workflow?

Comment: This is how it stands currently

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your updated sources in your second clone, you can import them in your first clone

```sh
cd /path/to/first/clone
git switch devbranch
git --work-tree=/path/to/second/clone add .
git commit -m "Import from second clone"
git push
```